# Get wordpress installation folder

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm writing a rewrite rule, accompanied by two additional rewrite tags, which (the tags) must apply only on a specific page. In the past, when I had to do something similar, I had done it like this:

```
add_action('init', 'publications_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
function publications_rewrite_rule()
{
    if (preg_match('/^\/publications\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        add_rewrite_tag('%date%', '([^&]+)');
        add_rewrite_tag('%publication%', '([^&]+)');
    }

    add_rewrite_rule('publications/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?$', 'index.php?page_id=370577&date=$matches[1]$matches[2]$matches[3]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('publications/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=370577&date=$matches[1]$matches[2]$matches[3]&publication=$matches[4]', 'top');
}
```

In my current project though, WP installation is in a folder, ie. `mydomain.tld/wordpress/`, so `preg_match()` won't match the beginning of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the page's slug `^\/quiz\/`. I know I can hardcode WP's installation folder in the pattern, ie. `^\/wordpress\/quiz\/` but I'd like to get it programmatically, so that it works in future projects as well...

So how do I get the whole path of the active WP installation? If it's not one folder, like `/wordpress/`, I want to get the whole path, like `/folder1/folder2/`, etc, so that I can prepend it to my search pattern and do it the right/safe way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this. As long as your site URL in Settings is set to `mydomain.tld/wordpress` you don't need to include `/wordpress` in your rewrite rules.

If you look at the `rewrite_rules` option in the `wp_options` table you'll see that none of the default rules are using it, because it's not required.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! How careless of me not noticing that earlier!